# Syntax error for Facebook API Graph - Help Require

Tags: string, facebook, facebook-graph-api, syntax-error, access-token

This is my URL for my Facebook graph API

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/8530412xxxx?fields=access_token,name,posts{shares,created_time,name,likes}?access_token=AACCXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

However, I'm facing some syntax error

```
{
       "error": {
          "message": "Syntax error \"Expected end of string instead of \"?\".\" at character 55: access_token,name,posts{shares,created_time,name,likes}?access_token=AACC",
          "type": "OAuthException",
          "code": 2500,
          "fbtrace_id": "FweuEUmRd2A"
      }
}
```

Can anyone help me generating me this URL ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/8530412xxxx?fields=access_token,name,posts.fields(shares,created_time,name,likes)&access_token=AACC
```

I found the answer after a bit researching.. This will be useful to those are facing similar issues like me.